# Clang on Windows with MinGW

Tags: windows, gcc, clang, clang++

I have both MinGW `gcc` and Clang `clang` installed and added to path via `chocolatey`, and both can be found on the command line. However, when I try to use `clang` with `gcc`, `clang` doesn't seem to know where to find header files in the standard library (such as `iostream`), returning the following error:

```sh
clang++ -v main.cpp -o main.exe -std=c++14 -target x86_64-mingw64
```

```
clang version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin
(SKIP)
ignoring nonexistent directory "(nonexistent directories)"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\9.0.0\include
End of search list.
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

shell returned 1
```

I've added both `gcc` and `clang` to path, as well as the directory containing header files included in `gcc` (`C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0`), so I don't understand why `clang` isn't looking in the right place for the header files. How can I fix this problem? And this isn't really necessary, but can the default target for `clang` be changed? The current Windows 10 default for `clang` is `msvc`, but I'd rather not use it.

Comment: clang and gcc are different compilers, what do you mean by "use clang with gcc" ?

Comment: Wait I thought I could use clang as a frontend for gcc with the compatible compiler driver. Is this something entirely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: 
edit your path environment, move or add [path to your g++ folder] to some position ahead of "C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin".

Reason:
LLVM installed using prebuilt binaries from chocolatey or its offcial website lacks header files, therefore it has to use header files of other compiles such as MSVC or mingw64. When you specify your target as mingw64, clang will guess path to header files of mingw by the position of g++.exe (maybe gcc.exe).
Chocolatey uses a software shimgen to "map" (I don't know if there is more proper word) executable file to "C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin", which is placed before [path to your g++ folder]. Therefore clang will detect "g++.exe" under that path first and infer a wrong path from it.

Please forgive my poor English.